# Issues with cache manifest and NETWORK section

Tags: firefox, html

I'm having an odd issue with the NETWORK section and wildcards. It is my understanding that if I do NETWORK: * and CACHE: X (where X is a list of files), then anything not in the CACHE list will be loaded when I'm online.

When I run Firebug though I can see my cache list is working, however, my requests for Google Maps

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
```

shows it not loading at all. It's like the NETWORK: * isn't working for the file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar.

According to various resources, including http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/offline/takingappoffline/, cross-domain requests are not possible.

EDIT: And from http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html

> The network section in this cache manifest also has just a single line, a line that contains just a single character (*). This character has special meaning in a network section. It’s called the “online whitelist wildcard flag.” That’s a fancy way of saying that anything that isn’t in the appcache can still be downloaded from the original web address, as long as you have an internet connection.

EDIT 2: While looking into another cache issue I'm seeing I found this other Stack Overflow question: [cache google map with HTML5 for iphone offline use error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001303/cache-google-map-with-html5-for-iphone-offline-use-error) . See in particular the only answer to the question.

Comment: Although, reading your question a third-time, this doesn't answer the question if you're not expecting it in your cache, but rather it's not loading at all. (Which wouldn't make sense, but ...)